# Eclipse Java debugger won't step into lambdas or method references

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

Using Eclipse Luna, I've been changing some of my Java code to use lambdas and method references instead of traditional control flow.

However, when trying to step through this new code in the Eclipse debugger, I've been unable to step into the interface calls with <kbd>F5</kbd>. Instead, the debugger skips over the call as though I had pressed <kbd>F6</kbd>. This obviously makes debugging very difficult.

How can I configure Eclipse to let me step into lambdas and method references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to go to **Java** > **Debug** > **Step Filtering** in Preferences, and enable the **Step through filters** option.